# Grouping many tables with similar structure but diferent meaning

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-normalization, entity-attribute-value

I have many tables with the follow structure

```
id(int autoinc)
name (varchar)
```

for definition of productoCategory, clientType, employeePosition, etc. It is a valid aproach group all this in one table with a name like "groupings"

```
id (int autoinc)
name (varchar)
table (varchar) <-- here especify the table that below this info(product, client, employee)
```

is a valid aproach? there will be problems with the scalability?

Comment: It mostly depends on your architecture. Usually, these "definition" tables are kept separate. It's easier in the long run. They're used as translation from ids to human readable values. If these tables grow too big, joining on them your require more resources (memory and time)

Comment: It almost will have around 500 records aprox

Comment: The comment in your code is not clear. It is atypical to store the table name as data, when the table is typically independent. Sometimes this is done because a table name plays the role of a subtype name for the id in a row. But then the table name is usually a function of the containing table, and the type is only present as data for SQL idioms enforcing constraints. Please give more info about your schema.

Comment: There is no way to 'join' to an arbitrary 'table'.  Rethink the schema design.  Beware of EAV.